# pandas create a dataframe with groupby function in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

what I have here is

```
ap = ['DMK','BKK','HKT','USM']
for i in ap:
    test1 = c[c['schedule_from'].isin(ap)].groupby(['schedule_from','schedule_to']).size().to_frame().reset_index().sort_values(['schedule_from',0],ascending=False)
    print((test1.loc[test1['schedule_from']==i]).head(5))
    print('____')
```

the output like

```
   schedule_from schedule_to   0
24           DMK         HKT  84
43           DMK         PNH  69
14           DMK         DMK  26
11           DMK         CNX  23
59           DMK         UTP  11
____
  schedule_from schedule_to  0
0           BKK         DMK  2
1           BKK         DXB  1
2           BKK         LTN  1
3           BKK         OTP  1
____
   schedule_from schedule_to   0
65           HKT         DMK  88
71           HKT         KUL   6
76           HKT         USM   3
64           HKT         CNX   2
66           HKT         DWC   2
____
   schedule_from schedule_to   0
80           USM         DMK  14
81           USM         HDY   1
82           USM         HKT   1
83           USM         NST   1
____
```

How to create 4 dataframe for each of the outcome, or one full dataframe if 4 isn't easy to get

Comment: You can create a dictionary and store each data frame under a different key

Comment: @Psidom can you provide an example of that? I only know create a whole data frame with different columns

Comment: `d = {}; for i in ap: test1 = ....; d[i] = test1` ?